# Command for obtaining plural form of forced short & long use of acronyms in glossaries-extra

Tags: glossaries, acronyms, glossaries-extra

The `glossaries-extra` user guide recommends the usage of `glsfmtshort` and `glsfmtlong` within section headings and table/figure captions.

The question is regarding the plural usage of these forced incantations. For example, let us say we have declared the following acronym

`\newacronym{adc}{ADC}{Analog to Digital Converter}`

Now, for plural usage within text, we can simply use `\glspl{adc}` and things work as expected. I wonder what would be its counterpart for use in a section heading.

For now, I am manually appending an `s` at the end, i.e.

> \section{Analysis of state of the art \glsfmtshort{adc}s for flash-conversion}

I am sure there is a pre-existing command provided by the package, but I am simply unable to find it in the manual. (probably owing to the shortcomings of my vocabulary. The manual is simply brilliant and comprehensive)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For using in headings and captions, the short plural form is obtained with `\glsfmtshortpl` and the long plural form is obtained with `\glsfmtlongpl`.

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries-extra}

\setabbreviationstyle{long-short}
\newacronym{adc}{ADC}{Analog to Digital Converter}

\begin{document}
\section{Analysis of state of the art \glsfmtshortpl{adc} for flash-conversion}

\end{document}
```

[image: 1 Analysis of state of the art ADCs for flash-conversion]